# why these modules are simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $D$ be a division ring, and $M_i$ the set of matrices $n\times n$ with coefficients in $D$ with a nonzero $i$th column and zeros elsewhere. Then $M_i$ is simple for all $i$. how can I prove this?

Comment: Dear Berry, Over what ring are you thinking of $M_i$ as a module? Regards,

Comment: as a module over $D$

Comment: Unless I misread it, $M_i \cong D^n$. Or am I too tired to think about this?

Comment: $M_i$ is not a simple module over $D$.  But it is simple over the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mt_ is right. To elaborate: As a module over $D$, $M_i$ is the direct sum of $n$ copies of $D$, thus it is far from being simple.

To show that it is simple over $D^{n \times n}$, let $m \in M_i$ be an arbitrary element, $m \neq 0$. Then, it is not too hard to show that $(D^{n \times n}) m = M_i$ (since $D$ is a division ring).